# Codename One: use one of mine CN1 Netbeans projects as a template

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

Every time that I start a Codename One project, in Netbeans I select the native theme and the "Hello World (Bare bones)" template, then I need to customize it (adding a theme which overlays another theme, adding the CSS support, my localization code, my customized crash report code, etc.).

Of course I don't like to repeat the same steps every time that I start a new project: is there a way to use one of mine projects as a Netbeans template inside the category "CodenameOne Project" (with already added all my customizations)?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Notice you can use a cn1lib for theme related changes too by using a different file name than theme.res and binding all the custom code you have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [Codename One CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codenameone-cli) tool to make things like this easier.

Installation (requires NodeJS):

```
$ sudo npm install -g codenameone-cli
```

Usage (creating a project with your own template)

```
$ cn1 create helloworld com.mycompany.hello HelloWorld \
    -i Netbeans \
    -t https://example.com/yourprojecttemplate.zip
```

After the first run you can ommit the -i flag (which indicates the IDE) as it will assume you want to use the same IDE as in the last run.

This would create a new project in the directory "helloworld", with package "com.mycompany.hello" and Main class named HelloWorld, but using the project template you provided.

The tool also includes a GUI wizard if you prefer to do this with a GUI rather than command-line flags:

```
$ cn1 create helloworld -g
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The following command produces something wrong, because the generated project doesn't compile (and the css folder is missing): `cn1 create '/home/francesco/NetBeansProjects/Test' it.galgani.cn1.demos.template MyApp -i Netbeans -t https://www.informatica-libera.net/codenameone/templates/demo.zip`

Comment: Actually.. just tried your command locally.  You just need to update the project libs.  Properties > Then click the "Update project libs" button.  And it will compile.  As for the css folder, looks like this tool doesn't currently copy the css folder.  I'll need to add that.

Comment: I just pushed up a change that will retain the css direcotory.  If you update using npm (e.g. `sudo npm install -g codenameone-cli) it will pick up the update.  Currently build.xml file cusomizations aren't retained, so you'd still need to add modifications for the css to be compiled

Comment: I'm sorry, your updated version launches an exception (and doesn't copy the /css folder), please see this output: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/b5f537acd5937271ec0453b98eb07f9c

Comment: I found the error: "demo.zip" is interpreted as "dem‌%E2%80%8Bo.zip", I don't know why. I've rewritten manually "demo.zip" in the command and it works without exception, but the css folder is not copied.

Comment: I just tried your command here (I get the same corrupted  "dem‌%E2%80%8Bo.zip" thing - perhaps something SO adds.  But it worked and retained the css directory.  Make sure you update codenameone-cli to the latest (essentially run npm install on it again).